# Phonegap 3.1 - run ios not supported

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, command-line-interface

I just upgraded to Phonegap 3.1. My understanding is that the commandline should now support installation on iOS 7. But when running:

```
phonegap run ios --device "[my phone]"
```

it says:

> An error occurred while running the ios project. Targeting a device is
>   not supported currently.

I have opened the .xcodeproj file in Xcode and installed the provisioning certificate. Running the app from Xcode works.

Was this feature removed from the release or am I doing something wrong and the error message is just off.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run directly on a device without using XCode.  It works for Android, but not iOS currently.

More on this [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/94).

You can run the command with -V for more verbose output: 
`phonegap -V run ios --device`